# Do apple-app-site-association files work with GitHub Pages (i.e. site.github.io)?

Tags: swift, passwords

I'm trying to setup strong passwords support for an app.

I have a valid JSON file with the correct items:

```
{
"appLinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [{}]
},
"webcredentials": {
    "apps": [ "<TEAMID>.<BUNDLEID>", "<TEAMID>.<BUNDLEID>" ]
}
```

}

I've included a ".nojekyll" file to the repo to allow for **.folder access**. I've validated that with (https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator).

I've placed the file in **/.well-known/apple-app-site-association**

I've added the capability to my app and triple checked my **TEAM ID** and **Bundle identifier**.

I've also **deleted the app from my device and installed** and run with and without a debugger attached.

I'm beginning to think **GitHub Pages** for some reason or another does not support this functionality.

NOTE: my bundleIDs are explicit, meaning instead of "com.company.app", I'm using "app"

Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: Also it seems the file doesn't need to be signed for iOS 9 and up. The Support Universal Links section of the App Search Programming Guide states:
If your app runs in iOS 9 or later and you use HTTPS to serve the apple-app-site-association file, you can create a plain text file that uses the application/json MIME type and you don’t need to sign it.

Comment: How did you create the ".well-known" folder?

Comment: Just structure it in your GitHub page publishing via some publishing tool or upload tool.

Comment: I was using macOS, which doesn't allow folders to start with ".". I borrowed a Windows to do it.

Comment: macOS does allow it, it just makes the file/folder invisible. Which should still upload once committing (depending on the tool).

Comment: “In Terminal, type mv filename .filename. This moves the original folder to one with a period at the beginning of its name; by default, folders with periods at the beginning of their names are hidden in OS X. You can also type mkdir .hiddenfolder to create a new hidden folder. In either case, you can again access the hidden folder using the Go To Folder option” - Macworld article

Comment: It's still not working. How did you get the MIME type to return "application/json"? Did you use Cloudflare? Here is what I have: http://jaydenirwin.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Comment: I would do some more searching. Also try using this... (https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/)

Comment: I did some research and found GitHub Pages returns different MIME types based on the extension of the file. Since apple doesn't allow me to add ".json", I don't see how GitHub Pages can work for this.

Comment: Here is a random example of a GitHub Pages served AppAssociationFile. I don't think the MIME matters in this case. Just remember not to add the .json extension. Also remember that the association file may take a few days to a week to become discovered by Apple's servers. There is a bunch of documentation on the web regarding this process.

https://github.com/zom/zom.github.io/blob/master/apple-app-site-association

Comment: Both my website and https://zom.im fail apple's validator tool: https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool Also I noticed zom doesn't have the file in a ".well-known" folder, and it is using older JSON keys like "appID" instead of the newer key "appIDs".

Comment: Looks like you must also include the ".nojekyll" file to disable Github's processing. Take a look at one of my own implimentations: https://github.com/uhohpro/uhohpro.github.io/

Comment: I have the ".nojekyll". Are you sure your implementation is working? Apple's validator says "Error cannot fetch app site association" for your website.

Comment: I haven't used that app in a while, but the last time I checked the desired effect was functional.

Answer (score 2):

*Nope*, I haven't been able to make it work with GitHub Pages alone. If you don't care why you can skip this next bit.

#### Why GitHub Pages alone can't suffice

As far as I've found out, GitHub Pages alone will *not* serve up a file at `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` with `Content-Type: application/json`. [Apple's validation tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool) wouldn't pass. It requires:

- `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` to be served (you can test with `curl -v mysite.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`)
- It must be served with a `Content-Type: application/json` header.
- There cannot be any redirects; i.e. must work *without* adding `-L` to your `curl` command.

Here's the solutions I tried using only GitHub pages that all failed:

1. First thing I figured out was adding `.nojekyll` to the top directory of the repo so that `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` could be served.trying to redirect with a symlink `apple-app-site-association` to `apple-app-site-association.json`

   - It was still served as `Content-Type: octet-stream`
2. Creating the directory/file structure `.well-known/apple-app-site-association/index.json`

   - This fails Apple validation because `mydomain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` redirects to `mydomain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association/` before returning the correct content and correct content-type header.

#### Cloudflare/CDN atop GH Pages Solution

However, I was also using [Cloudflare to CDN the static pages my GitHub Pages site hosted](https://blog.cloudflare.com/secure-and-fast-github-pages-with-cloudflare/). You can set this up at the free level and probably should if your page gets any real traffic. You could pick another CDN probably, but it will need custom routing of some kind that supports the content-type/no-redirect stuff Apple demands. In Cloudflare, I was able to effect this for free (unless I got a *ton* of traffic) with the free tier of their Workers. You can probably adapt the rest of this to your preferred CDN if you use another atop your GitHub Pages site.

From the "Workers" page on Cloudflare, click "Manage Workers" then "Create Worker." Copy/paste and the following JSON as needed (it contains your `apple-app-site-association` JSON):

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

/**
 * Respond to the request
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(
  // This is actually your JSON. Because this is JavaScript, you can also add in comments if you like.
{
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
         "appID": "Q94XRK95RT.io.beatscratch.beatscratchFlutterRedux",
         "paths": [ "/app/", "/app"]
      }
    ]
   }
}) + "\n"
, {
  headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
  status: 200
  })
}
```

Note that I had to use the JSON structure from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html). This got the above-linked validator to display "Error no apps associated with url" which sounds bad... but things work.

I named the Worker `apple-app-site-association` but you can name it whatever you like. You can then route `my-site.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` to the Worker.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It did end up actually working off of the GitHub Page (<name>.github.io) several months ago.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `_config.yml` file to the root of your GitHub page, then the `<domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` can be accessed properly.

```
// _config.yml
include: [".well-known"]
```

Comment: If that fails in github pages build use with yml format: include:
  - .well-known

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like once the app has been uploaded and installed via TestFlight strong passwords and the association file is accessed.

It works!

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021 this currently works for me with a custom Github Pages domain even though:

- github pages does not serve `apple-app-site-association` with the correct json content-type -- it's `octet-stream` instead of `application/json`.
- the apple validation tool fails the universal link test

If you redirect from the apex domain to `www` then you'll probably need to specify the full `www.yourdomain.com` in your app config, not `yourdomain.com`.

Make sure this returns the file.

```sh
curl -v '<the_domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association'
```

Comment: Thank you! The “www” part was the last thing I needed to do!